# Add extra column to dataframe with specific words from existing column

Tags: python, pandas

I am new in Python and am struggling with Pandas. More specifically I have a column (Sensory scores) in a dataframe that consists of multiple words like this:

```
*Treatment*  *Sensory scores*
A                soft, short
B                soft, tender
C                short, tender
```

Now I want to add extra columns "soft', 'short' and ' tender' to the dataframe whereby the individual scores are extracted and quantified like this:

```
 *Treatment*  *Sensory scores*  *soft*  *short*  *tender*
A                soft, short       1        1       0
B                soft, tender      1        0       1
C                short, tender     0        1       1
```

What is the best way to program this in Pandas? Any help, suggestions are appreciated. Many thanks in advance.
Coen

Answer (score 1):

You need first to split the values, then you can use pivot_table to sum a dummy column (count):

```
df = df.set_index("*Treatment*")
df = pd.DataFrame(df["*Sensory scores*"].str.split(', ').explode())
df["count"] = 1
df = df.pivot_table(index=df.index, columns="*Sensory scores*", fill_value=0)
```

Comment: Thank you very much Ronkov! Your suggestion works and is exactly what I needed!

Comment: @Coen you're welcome! Validate my answer if it works, thanks!